# Which hard drive is in better condition according to the tests performed?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, benchmarking

I have two hard drives, both 500GB Samsung, but it catches my attention that when I test the disk performance, the graph of the results show a very different behavior ... What could this mean? Which you could say is in better conditions?

[image]
<sup>**Disk 1**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Disk 2**</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by "condition"? Think one will fail soon, any errors or noises? Checked the smart data?

Comment: With "better condition" I mean wich one have the expected behavior. Or in any case, what does it mean to have a chart with such different behavior?

Comment: They are different models of disk drive, so it is reasonable to expect different performance.

Comment: They are quasi the same. I would not worry about it.

Comment: test speed could depend on the current usage - if one hard disk is fuller or has its files distributed differently, you might get those differences just from that.